# Kafka real time average for last X minutes

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic on a single broker with constantly incoming data about user clicks. I want to be able to calculate average number of clicks in last X minutes per user in near real time (1 second for instance).

I tried doing it with Kafka streams but the problem is that thumbling window cannot calculate in near real time and update average every second for all the values IN LAST X minutes. Hopping window could maybe suit but for hop=1 second and a window of size 5 minutes it would create 300 windows and I guess it's too much looking from a performance side.

Is there a way to do it without 3rd party streaming engine as Spark, but with "plain" Kafka APIs? (Kafka streaming is optional).

Thanks alot!

Comment: You can always build a custom solution via Kafka Streams Processor API.

Comment: If you care about performance, why do you have only one broker? KSQL or Kafka Streams is the answer you're looking for

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Ok, I'm pretty aware of it. Any guidelines? How to manage and save state? How to access stream values in last X hours etc. ...?

Comment: @cricket_007 Single broker is not a production setup, but it doesn't matter, I said it for simplicity sake. Could you give some guideliness on how to do it with KSQL or Kafka Streams?

Comment: I guess you need to read the docs and ask more specific question in SO :)

Comment: The problem is I read all of it but couldn't find a thing about my situation.

Answer (score 4):

As commenters have said - use [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/), or [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-open-source-streaming-sql-for-apache-kafka/). KSQL runs on top of Kafka Streams, and so the data modelling and concepts such as windowing and aggregations are the same.

In KSQL:

```
ksql> CREATE TABLE USER_CLICKS_PER_MINUTE AS \
SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(*) AS CLICK_COUNT, \
COUNT(*)/5 AS CLICKS_PER_MINUTE \
FROM RATINGS WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 5 MINUTES, ADVANCE BY 1 SECOND) \
GROUP BY USER_ID;

 Message
---------------------------
 Table created and running
---------------------------
```

Query the stateful aggregate:

```
ksql> SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), USER_ID, \
CLICK_COUNT, CLICKS_PER_MINUTE \
FROM USER_CLICKS_PER_MINUTE \
WHERE USER_ID=18;
2018-05-09 11:44:33 | 18 | 7 | 1
2018-05-09 11:44:34 | 18 | 7 | 1
2018-05-09 11:44:35 | 18 | 7 | 1
2018-05-09 11:44:36 | 18 | 9 | 1
2018-05-09 11:44:37 | 18 | 9 | 1
2018-05-09 11:44:38 | 18 | 10 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:39 | 18 | 10 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:40 | 18 | 10 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:41 | 18 | 12 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:42 | 18 | 12 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:43 | 18 | 12 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:44 | 18 | 12 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:45 | 18 | 12 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:46 | 18 | 12 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:47 | 18 | 12 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:48 | 18 | 12 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:49 | 18 | 12 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:50 | 18 | 12 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:51 | 18 | 13 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:52 | 18 | 13 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:53 | 18 | 13 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:54 | 18 | 13 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:55 | 18 | 13 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:56 | 18 | 13 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:57 | 18 | 13 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:58 | 18 | 13 | 2
2018-05-09 11:44:59 | 18 | 13 | 2
2018-05-09 11:45:00 | 18 | 13 | 2
2018-05-09 11:45:01 | 18 | 13 | 2
```

Bear in mind that Kafka Streams and KSQL (which is built upon Kafka Streams) will re-emit aggregates for a given time window as new events arrive. Depending on your requirements, an actual hopping window advancing every 1 second may not be what you want. A simple tumbling window that is updating in realtime will still give you realtime results of the stateful aggregates.

More info on KSQL here:

- https://www.confluent.io/product/ksql/
- [KSQL docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/index.html#ksql-home)
- [KSQL syntax reference](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/syntax-reference.html)
- [KSQL Quickstart tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-quickstart.html)
- [KSQL video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa7VYi0yPIH2eX8q3mPpZAn3qCS1eDX8W)

Comment: Thanks Robin! Well, the only actual info I'm interested is the current or the latest window 'cause it actually tells aggregation results in near real time (from now minus 5 minutes). Thumbling window aggregates events and after window finishes i get a "final" 5 minute result. I'm actually interested in the result being updated each second. So your hopping window might be what I need but I'm wondering if spawning 300 windows poses a performance problem or is it ok?

Comment: Maybe I'm getting hopping windows wrong also? So the point is not to open the window and then wait for the events to come in for 5 minutes and aggregate them in the end, but to look from this moment minus 5 minutes and aggregate them, and doing so each second. Thumbling window as I get it opens new window after 5 minutes, and starts new aggregation so it ignores events that came at 4:59, but in 5:01 i want to aggregate events from 0:01 to 5:01 that's why I was thinking about hopping window, to "get rid" of events older than 5 minutes and doing it each second.

Comment: You're misunderstanding windows. A five minute tumbling window will still be evaluated _as events arrive_ and the aggregate values re-emitted by Kafka Streams or KSQL. So you get a realtime view of the current state of your aggregates - it's just the period over which you want to evaluate them. But regardless of the window _size_, the results are emitted in _real time_. See if this helps: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing-hopping

Comment: Tumbling will reset when it moves to next time windows. A window will always start from 0.